# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'. after creating the EDIT View

Tags: c#

Getting this error executing the EDIT View  during the  [HttpPost] or SAVE action.

This is the first time Saving Changes to the Edited Data and the form does a dump giving the above error.

Changed a field from decimal to string and thought that was the problem but thinking now it is NOT.  Made the change in the database - then edited the Model from:

```
    public Nullable<decimal> F_RENO { get; set; }
```

to:

```
    public string F_RENO { get; set; }
```

and in the  Metadata I have:

```
    [Display(Name = "R.E. NO.")]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string F_RENO;
```

Also edited the  `MTSMODEL.EDMX`  for the table/field  from decimal - to string

Is there somewhere  else I missed? Should the table be remove from the `.EDMX` then re-added?

Everything seemed to work until I tried to Edit the record.

Comment: `Nullable<decimal>` and `string` are completely different things. there are other parts that causes problem. you cant change it by just changing the type to string.

Comment: Where _exactly_ are you getting the error?  What's the stack trace?

Comment: What is an `F_RENO`? Why do you think it should be a string instead of a decimal?

Comment: You should use the "update model from database" option in the esmx file

Comment: F_RENO is  Resident Engineer number - except now they want it to be alpha numeric so the can have something like C01. Before it was a number(2) in SQL and I changed it to varchar(3).

Comment: Will do the update and see if that helps.  Get the error when I select  SAVE on the EDIT view.

Comment: UPDATED model from database  and  it  updated the model  - but it is still not working

Comment: UPDATED model from database  and  it  updated the model  - but it is still not working   Not sure how to add the dump.   Would removing the metadata or the partial class where  the display field names and other format  statements are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Metadata for this Model. My Model nameed mts_aggrtest when  completely removed the  Models.Metadata.mts_aggrtestMetadata   the EDIT view was able to save Edits. In one of the 90+ fields  there probable is [StringLength(xx)]  on a  numeric field or something similar.  Bad Programming  not enough testing.